# Arcpy.Intersect_analysis problem

Tags: arcpy, syntax

I am very new to Python, after using ArcGIS for a few years (Toolbox only).

I thought I'd get stuck in and try and pick it up as I went along, but I've come to a stumbling block with Intersect_analysis.

The below image shows the issue I am having after trying to follow the syntax in the ESRI guidance; I was hoping someone could point out what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Parameter join_attributes should be data type String so change ALL to "ALL"

Comment: Please always include error messages as text rather than pictures so that they are available to future searches by others with the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the Code Samples in the [help for Intersect tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/intersect.htm). For example you need to change ALL to 'ALL' since it is a string (you dont really have to specify this since it is an optional parameter with default value 'ALL').

Try code below. Change names in featurelist and path+name for outfc

```
import arcpy
featurelist = ['feature1','feature2','feature3']
outfc = r'C:\test.gdb\test'

arcpy.Intersect_analysis (in_features=featurelist, out_feature_class=outfc, cluster_tolerance=1.5, output_type='POINT')
```